# at command +CME ERROR: 4 C#

Tags: c#

please help wavecom at command :

reply :

+STIN : 3
+STGI: 0,1,8,8,0,"Date: (Example: 12081965)"

OK
AT+STGR=3,1

> 12192011

+CME ERROR: 4

```
port.DataBits = 8;
port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
port.Parity = Parity.None;
port.ReadTimeout = 800;
port.WriteTimeout = 800;
port.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
port.Open();
port.DiscardOutBuffer();
port.DiscardInBuffer();

port.WriteLine("AT+STGR=3,1\r");

Thread.Sleep(100);

port.WriteLine("12192011" + (char)36);
```

Comment: Please tell us more.  What equipment are you using?  What are you trying to accomplish with your code?  You seem to be communicating with a modem that uses an `AT` command set.

Comment: Try changing the final `char` that you are sending to the modem to a decimal 26 -- this is the value for CTRL-Z which seems to be what is required for an `AT` command like this one.  So change the last posted line of code to: `port.WriteLine("12192011" + (char)26);` and tell us if you get a different response back from the modem.